# Dependency Management on Synology DS415+

Tags: artifactory, nas, archiva, synology

I want to set up a repository manager for dependencies and after reading online for a bit came to Artifactory and Apache Archiva. Sadly I can't for the life of me get them to work on the Tomcat7 available on the DS415+.

I've tried deploying them as war files and get the following exception:

**Artifactory**

```
Mar 23, 2015 11:35:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.logback.LogbackConfigListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.logback.LogbackConfigListener.contextDestroyed(LogbackConfigListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:694)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The one for Archiva is ridiculously long so never mind about that.

I thought that maybe it was a problem with Artifactory's home and permissions to it but I've already changed ARTIFACTORY_HOME to a directory I know and set rwx permissions for everyone.

Comment: maybe try archiva :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just installed the newest Tomcat, outside of Synology's Package Center and it worked like a charm. Artifactory is now running.

[EDIT]

If anyone is interested, you should know that applications installed independently from the Package Manager will always terminate upon log out. To avoid this, you can add a startup script to the /usr/local/etc/rc.d folder so that your script is ran whenever the station boots up. Refer to the scripts in /usr/local/syno/etc/rc.d to figure out the syntax.